# Transchoice in Symfony translations

Tags: php, symfony

I have these PHP translation strings in my language file:

```
'string.month'                         => '1 month',
'string.months'                        => '%month% months',
```

And I'm using this in my Twig file:

```
{% transchoice data.frequencyInMonths() with {'%month%': data.frequencyInMonths()} from "strings" %}
{0,[2,Inf]} string.months|trans({'%month%' : data.frequencyInMonths()})|{1} string.month|raw
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Obviously this isn't working though. I just want to get `string.month` used `data.frequencyInMonths() == 1`, and `string.months` with the number injected in for everything else (ie. 0 and 2 to Infinity).

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest way** to solve your problem is here:

*translate file code:*

```
'string.months':       'one month|%count% months'
```

*twig file code:*

```
{% set count = data.frequencyInMonths() %}
{{ "string.months"|transchoice(count) }}
```

The **complex way**, if you need a special 0 month message (none month):

*translate file code:*

```
'string.months': '{0} none months|{1} one month|]1,Inf] %count% months'
```

*twig file code is same as the last time:*

```
{% set count = data.frequencyInMonths() %}
{{ "string.months"|transchoice(count) }}
```

**Remark:**
You don't have use ' character at the first value of the translation, so you can use any time:

```
string.month: 'something about month'
```

If your translation(the second value) is simple string. So if the "something about month" string isn't contain any special character, then you can you can use:

```
string.month: something about month
```